# retrieve value from One-To-Many relationship Hibernate Without HQL

Tags: java, html, hibernate, jsp

I just try to retrieve a value from One-To-Many relationship in Hibernate. But I stuck with getting values.

> *here is the scenario - There are centre and staff. the centre just like Branch of office. and it has a staff member assigned to centre*
>   one staff member can assign more centres.

There is three table called "centres", "staff" and "centerhasstaff". 
here is the structure of the table [Picture of ER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChJD4.png)

I need to get 'name' from staff table who assigned to centre by searching centre.

Here is my POJO files

Center.java

```
 private Integer idCenter;
 private Branch branch;
 private String centerName;
 private String centerDay;
 private String centertime;
 private String isApprove;
 private String isActive;
 private String createdBy;
 private String centerNo;
 private Set centerHasStaffs = new HashSet(0);
```

CenterHasStaff.java

```
 private Integer idcenterHasStaff;
 private Center center;
 private Staff staff;
```

Staff.java

```
private Integer idStaff;
 private String nic;
 private String licenceNo;
 private String name;
 private String address1;
 private String address2;
 private String city;
 private Set centerHasStaffs = new HashSet(0);
```

here is how I try to retrieve Staff name on JSP Page.

```
 <%                    
                int i = 1;

                Session ss = DB.getSession();
                Criteria crr = ss.createCriteria(Center.class);
                crr.add(Restrictions.eq("isActive", "Active"));
                crr.add(Restrictions.eq("isApprove", "Approve"));

                List<Center> li = crr.list();

                for (Center el : li) { %>

            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><%= i++ %></th>
                <td><%= el.getCenterNo() %></td>
                <td><%= el.getCenterName() %></td>
                <td><%= el.getCenterDay() %></td>
                <td><%= el.getCentertime() %></td>
                <td><%= el.getCenterHasStaffs() %></td>
                <td><%= el.getCreatedBy() %></td>
                <td>OK</td>
            </tr>

            <%  }%>
```

Here is my resultset like

[Image of Resultset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmMIK.png)

**

> Is there way to get staff name assigned to centre without using HQL??

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just found Solution for my problem. Is this better way to do that?

```
<%

        Iterator it = el.getCenterHasStaffs().iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {

        CenterHasStaff elem = (CenterHasStaff) it.next();
        out.print(elem.getStaff().getNameWithinitials());

                             }


%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the resultset and object graph, this is returning you a list back

```
<td><%= el.getCenterHasStaffs() %></td>
```

Assuming the center has 1 staff assigned, then you can grab the first item from the list

```
<td><%= el.getCenterHasStaffs().get(0).getName() %></td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. I try with your solution. when I try to get() method. its throw cannot find symbol error.

Comment: You may have to import the classes in the JSP?

Comment: Still Not fixed. only available "getClass()" only.